# how to solve the net work adaption error in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

when iam runnig the code i will get the error Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

```
package com.karunakar.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SelectAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"," system","1234") ;
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery( " select*from stu");
        while( rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+".."+rs.getString(2));
        }
        con.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Various questions here. First of all, is your database running in the background? Can you share the whole stacktrace in order to get a better look at what's happening?

Comment: IIRC, the connection URL should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe`.